# How to write vector<uint_8> to a file in c++?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have vector<uint_8> data filled and want to write this data into a file using c++? Tried out but didn't find any reference.

```
const std::vector<uint8_t>  buffer; // let's assume that i'ts filled with values
std::ofstream out("file.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
out.write(&buffer, buffer.size());
```

but not successfull. Also is it correct to open file in binary mode for this?

Comment: `out.write(buffer.data(), buffer.size());`

Comment: invalid conversion from ‘const unsigned char*’ to ‘const char*. Getting this error after trying out Eljay..

Comment: Use a `static_cast<const char*>(...)` on the first argument.

Comment: Or rather `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: out.write(static_cast<const char*>(buffer.data()), buffer.size()); then getting error "invalid static_cast from type ‘const unsigned char*’ to type ‘const char*" Adrian.

Comment: After "reinterpret cast" getting filled in the fie like this "x^A^@^@T^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^H^@^@^".. So not able to get the data from the file, Holyblackcat..

Comment: Is your `buffer` actually filled with values that we were supposed to assume?

Comment: What output are you expecting?  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: "getting filled in the fie like this" Are you looking at your file with a text editor? If you have text data, use `std::string`. If you have binary data, try a binary file viewer.

Comment: @sureshm Then you're reading the file incorrectly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Maybe, I will check once about it..

Comment: Thank you all, I tried to convert it to str, each character as suggested by Abstract. It works now./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the data pointer as recommended by others:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> temp;
    temp.push_back(97);
    temp.push_back(98);
    temp.push_back(99);

    const std::vector<uint8_t>  buffer(temp); // let's assume that i'ts filled with values
    std::ofstream out("file.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer.data()), buffer.size());
    out.close();
}
```

**Output: file.txt**

```
abc
```

If you're viewing this via a text file containing binary data (uint8_t), you'll expect to see the following in the file where each `uint8_t` corresponds with an ascii symbol:

https://www.asciitable.com/

If your intention is to write the integer values to the file instead of the raw binary data, then you would do this instead:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> temp;
    temp.push_back(97);
    temp.push_back(98);
    temp.push_back(99);

    const std::vector<uint8_t>  buffer(temp); // let's assume that i'ts filled with values
    std::ofstream out("file.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    for (auto v : buffer)
    {
        std::string str = std::to_string(v);
        out.write(str.c_str(), str.length());
    }
    out.close();
}
```

**Output: file.txt**

```
979899
```